# Does every countable sequence of ordinals converge?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $A=\{ \alpha_n | n \in \omega \}$ a monotonic increasing sequence. Can we say that there exists an $\alpha \in ON$ such that $\alpha = \lim_{n \in \omega} \alpha_n$?

i am asking this because I am trying to show that the set of fixed points of a normal function is a club set/ I know that there is a proof in the literature but I want my own proof. Proving the "closed" part is easy. For the "unbounded" part. I suppose it is bounded by $\alpha$ and then apply f (the normal function). So $\beta_0 = \alpha$ $\beta_n = f^n(\alpha)$. The only thing left is to say that $\{ \beta_n \}$ has a limit in ON..

tnx

Comment: You don’t even need $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ to be *strictly* increasing: either it has a strictly increasing subsequence, or it’s eventually constant, and in either case its limit is $\bigcup_n\alpha_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: *if* increasing (@DanielFischer), consider $\alpha=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n$.

Comment: Yes I thought about it. But how can I prove that $\alpha=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n$ is greater from $\alpha_n$ for each $n$?

Comment: How can you prove that $\alpha=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n$ is an ordinal?

Comment: @Astudent. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28908/a-transitive-set-of-ordinals-is-an-ordinal.

Comment: @user83081, $\alpha_n\in\alpha_{n+1}\subset\alpha$.

Comment: @user83081: If the $\alpha_n$'s are strictly increasing that sort of takes care of itself, right? The union is an ordinal that has as one of its members $\alpha_n$, since this will itself be a member of $\alpha_{m>n}$.